# Postgresql unique timestamp restriction

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    id int,
    registered timestamp without timezone, 
    primary_key(id, registered)
);
```

While running unit tests I got these sort of errors.

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key
>   value violates unique constraint "test_table_pkey" E       DETAIL: 
>   Key (id, registered)=(5, 2018-04-20 14:56:15.757907) already exists.

Meanwhile in the table there was only (5, datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 20, 14, 56, 15, 731178)) record. They were few milliseconds apart, which
according to postgresql documentation should be reflected as different timestamp, because the resolution is microseconds.

Meanwhile, I can just sleep the thread while doing tests, it's kind of important for me to understand what's happening here, while updating the
row I use `NOW()`. But these two inserts are done in different transactions and it returns different timestamps so, I don't think it's because
of transaction specific stuff.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Evidently you are inserting a duplicate id and timestamp. If you use `NOW()`, its value will be the same within a given transaction. You say you are using different transactions, but is any one of those transactions inserting multiple records, OR is your python code setting the values and inserting a duplicate record in multiple transactions?

Comment: Two inserts are done in different transactions. Each transation is updating one and only one row.

Comment: Are the values to insert being provided in the python code or purely at the postgres level?

Comment: `NOW()` is the only part that is being generated by postgresql, everything else is provided.

Comment: I suspect a single transaction is still involved. Can't think how else `NOW()` would return the same value. Try this: enable full logging, and add `%v` to the log prefix, which will log the "virtual txid". Perform your inserts, then check the log file after it fails and see whether the txids of those two inserts are the same or not.

Comment: Also you could try changing `NOW()` to `clock_timestamp()`. That will always give the current time at the point it's called. If that works fine, then you know the issue is transaction-related.

Comment: The timestamps returned are few milliseconds off, so I don't see how it can be the case that they are the same (?). Iquery the database right before inserting in it and when I look at the exception the timestamps diferent from what's in the table. I will try clock_timestamp().